i am using fcm kreait kit to send fcm notifiction. it is woking well but my action_click is not working here
push notification is working well but action_click not working with that
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Notification;

use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\WebPushConfig;

function fcmSendPush($deviceTokens,$title,$body,$iconImage,$url){
    $factory = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount('./firebase-adminkey.json');

    $messaging = $factory->createMessaging();
    
    if(count($deviceTokens) == 0) {
        return "Invalid device tokens array";
    }

    // config for FCM web/desktop push
    $config = WebPushConfig::fromArray([
        'notification' => [
            'title' => $title,
            'body' => $body,
            'icon' => $iconImage,
            'image' => $url,
            'action_click' => 'https//abc.com'
        ]
    ]);

    $message = $message = CloudMessage::new(); 
    $message = $message->withWebPushConfig($config);
    return $messaging->sendMulticast($message, $deviceTokens);


}

here title body icon and image are woking well but action_click is not working
action_click

